# Does Geofire support offline persistence?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching, geofire

One of the great things about Firebase is the ready-to-go offline persistence.

Using the iOS and Android SDKs, when you attach an observer to a reference, the values that are returned get cached (if `persistenceEnabled` is set to `YES`), and are available if your app is offline, and are used as a point of comparison to fire change events when a new observer is attached later. That's great.

But my question is whether it's possible to get [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js) caching in the same or a similar way, or does the app need to be online to get anything back from Geofire queries? And when a Geofire query returns something, does that get cached?

After much googling I haven't found any mention of offline persistence in relation to Geofire so I'm assuming it is online only, but if anyone can clarify that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

GeoFire is a library on top of the Firebase Realtime Database. It does not have its own storage layer, but instead depends on RTDB for all its data storage needs.

So if you enable disk persistence on RTDB, the data that GeoFire loads will be persisted to disk. If you run a GeoFire query while offline, the query will execute against the data from the disk cache.

But there are many known edge cases with Firebase RTDB's disk persistence, so you should definitely try if it works for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful to know it's at least worth trying it. And thanks for all your other posts about offline persistence - they've helped getting to grips with firebase offline syncing.

Comment: @Frank is geofire has any option to use keepSynced?